# Why This destructure property not working

Tags: reactjs

When  I try to destructure the Bookcontext in my `booklis.jsx` it's not working and it shows:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'books' of 'Object(...)(...)'
> as it is undefined.

**bookcontext.jsx**

// functional component

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const Bookcontext = createContext();


const BookcontextProvider = (props) => {
    const [books, setBook] = useState([
        { title: ' Name of the wind ', id: 1 },
        { title: ' Name of the Blind ', id: 2 },
        { title: ' Name of the Love', id: 3 },
        { title: ' Name of the Shine  ', id: 4 },
    ])
    return (
        <div>
            <BookcontextProvider value={{ books }}>
                {props.childrean}
            </BookcontextProvider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BookcontextProvider;
```

**booklis.jsx**

import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Themcontext } from "../Context/Themcontext";
import { Bookcontext } from "../Context/Bookcontext";

/// How to use context in functional component hare is the demu

```
const Booklis = () => {
  const { isLightThem, light, dark } = useContext(Themcontext);

  const { books, setbook } = useContext(Bookcontext);
  const theme = isLightThem ? light : dark;

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="book-list"
        style={{ color: theme.sintex, background: theme.bg }}
      >
        <ul>
          {books.map((boe) => {
            return (
              <li key={boe.id} style={{ background: theme.ui }}>
                {boe.title}{" "}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Booklis;
```

Comment: Is `Booklis` rendered within the `BookcontextProvider`'s React tree? Also, you don't pass  `setbook` to the context's value nor provide a valid initial context value.

Comment: isn't there a typo there : ```{props.childrean}``` shoudln't be ```{props.children}``` ?

Answer (score 0):

`useContext(Bookcontext);` Will return the value you passed into the provider.

So if your provider looks like

```
 <BookcontextProvider value={{ books }}>
       {props.childrean}
 </BookcontextProvider>
```

useContext will only return books as part of that object..

You need to add setBook to the value like so

```
<BookcontextProvider value={{ books, setBook }}>
       {props.childrean}
 </BookcontextProvider>
```

Comment: It's Work . Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of typos but the most important of those is: `childrean`. It should be `children`.

You are not returning the right thing from your context provider.

```
<BookcontextProvider value={{ books }}>
    {props.children}
</BookcontextProvider>
```

should be

```
<Bookcontext.Provider value={{ books }}>
    {props.children}
</Bookcontext.Provider>
```

Lastly, you are not wrapping the `Booklist` component with your provider, you should.

```js
const Bookcontext = React.createContext();

const BookcontextProvider = (props) => {
  const [books, setBook] = React.useState([
    { title: " Name of the wind ", id: 1 },
    { title: " Name of the Blind ", id: 2 },
    { title: " Name of the Love", id: 3 },
    { title: " Name of the Shine  ", id: 4 }
  ]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Bookcontext.Provider value={{ books }}>
        {props.children}
      </Bookcontext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

function Booklist() {
  const { books } = React.useContext(Bookcontext);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="book-list">
        <ul>
          {books.map((book) => {
            return <li key={book.id}>{book.title} </li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function Main() {
  return (
    <BookcontextProvider>
      <Booklist />
    </BookcontextProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Main />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Also, if you want to update the booklist you should pass the setter function via your context.

```
<Bookcontext.Provider value={{ books, setBooks }}>
```

```js
const Bookcontext = React.createContext();

const BookcontextProvider = (props) => {
  const [books, setBook] = React.useState([
    { title: " Name of the wind ", id: 1 },
    { title: " Name of the Blind ", id: 2 },
    { title: " Name of the Love", id: 3 },
    { title: " Name of the Shine  ", id: 4 }
  ]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Bookcontext.Provider value={{ books, setBook }}>
        {props.children}
      </Bookcontext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

const Booklist = () => {
  const { books, setBook } = React.useContext(Bookcontext);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  function addBook() {
    setBook((prev) => [...prev, { id: prev.length + 1, title: inputValue }]);
    setInputValue("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="book-list">
        <ul>
          {books.map((book) => {
            return <li key={book.id}>{book.title} </li>;
          })}
        </ul>
        <div>
          <input
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
          />{" "}
          <button onClick={addBook}>Add new book</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function Main() {
  return (
    <BookcontextProvider>
      <Booklist />
    </BookcontextProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Main />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: It's work Thank you soo much . love from Bangladesh